# How to bind textblock with property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a textblock in .xaml and declared a property in the .cs file named WrodName. How do I bind that property with textblock. I need the code which we write in the xaml code of  tag i.e. DataContext code. Till now I came up with this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WordName}"/>
```

And in .cs file:

```
public String WordName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set DataContext from xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ApplicationName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

But in that case you m=must assign the value before Initialize():

```
   WordName = "word";
   InitializeComponent();
```

Or from code-behind like that:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

But anyway I am recommending you to use MVVM architecture with INOtifyPropertyChanged event. In that case UI will update whenever property is set to a new value.

Comment: Lemme try this and get back to you. Meanwhile thanks

Comment: No that didnt worked out form me. I am initialising the value of wordname in constructor so is it ok or not

Comment: You need to assign the value before Initialize() or implement iNotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yeahh i just checked your answer again thanx for the info of setting property before InitializeComp()

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the DataContext.  A quick way of doing this is to set it in the constructor `DataContext = this;`

Also you will need to either set the property before you call `InitalizeComponent()` or preferably implment INotifyPropertyChanged.  Otherwise your UI will not update when the property is set.

See - [XAML: Binding a property in a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748578/xaml-binding-a-property-in-a-datatemplate)

A quick example

```
class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private String _wordName;
        public String WordName 
        {
            get { return _wordName; }
            set
            {
                if (_wordName != value)
                {
                     _wordName= value;
                     OnPropertyChanged("WordName");
                }

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the PropertyChanged notification in a thread safe manner
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for this code. It is helping me understand how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yeah, without it even if you binding is correct, your UI will not update without it.  If you set your property before `InitializeComponent()` but it doesn't update after that it's probably something wrong with INotifyPropertyChange.  This is the pattern we use in our production code.  I think it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel class

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public String WordName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your code behind of your view set the itemssource

```
public class MyView
{
   this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();

}
```

There are diff ways to set the datacontext either in code or in xaml. Really an preference thing.

Answer (score 0):

This will bind to your property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WordName,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Also set DataContext in your ctor:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, by ElementName. first naming the window:

```
<Window x:Class="ApplicationName" x:Name=AnyName ...
```

then bind to window element:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding WordName, ElementName=AnyName}"/>
```