# binding MySQL database with ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, listbox

I have a MySQL database containing of images and texts that want binding it to ListBox in WPF project; here is my code that have exception error, how can I fix that?

[image]

```
public DataTable GetTable(String query, String sortBy)
{
    String connString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=database_clothes";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = sortBy;
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: It says that you don't have database `database_clothes` on that server. Did you check that?

Comment: yes Chetan Ranpariya it exists on local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this exception  said  taht   your  connection  is invalid.
i think  the  database name  is not  correct.
after  resolve this problem ,
you  should map  your  datatable  to  observablecollection  then   can  binde  observablecollection  to  your  ListBox

here  you can find  good  description

[How to bind ObservableCollection with Listbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128666/how-to-bind-observablecollection-with-listbox-in-wpf)

Comment: where is your link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128666/how-to-bind-observablecollection-with-listbox-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Just answering my question!
the problem was not mysql authentication despite of error message,
here was my problem in sql commands in xaml file where the table name "names" was not as mine:

```
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="NamesTable"
ObjectType="{x:Type local:DatabaseTable}"
MethodName="GetTable">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <s:String>SELECT * FROM names</s:String>
            <s:String>Name</s:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```